# Search Server Express 2010 - No result with FQL Query

Tags: search

I have some problems with FQL queries: I want to select data from some BDC indexed with Search.

This is my query:
 or(myField:"240",myField:"300")

myfield is a custom property created on Search Server. myField always equals to "240 300 270", but no result appear with this Query... any Idea?

Comment: Are you able to view the item by querying a different field's value? You might want to validate the item has been indexed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use FQL (FAST Query Language) with Search Server Express 2010 or even the SharePoint Search Service Application. It can only be used with FAST.

Comment: Hum ok, I'll try to use SQL instead of FQL!
Thank you!

Comment: By the way, FAST Server is the commercial version of Search Server Express?

Comment: No. You have Search Server Express (free). Then you have Microsoft SharePoint Server with standard SP search and then you have FAST for SharePoint.